# How to root Vodafone 858 (froyo) / Huawei u8160

Tags: rooting, 2.2-froyo

I have a *Vodafone 858* smart phone running Froyo (Android 2.2). Manufacturer is Huawei (u8160). How can I root this device?

Comment: While waiting for an answer, you might wish to take a look into our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575), which names some "generic methods" including those working with Froyo – maybe one of them works with your device. If it did, please come back here and answer your own question to let other users of this device know :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the recommended tool would be SuperOneClick. It seems that this is malware infested though. Apparently most sites took down their downloads, so maybe it is indeed bad.  I tried to find another tool and found this:
http://www.kingoapp.com/android-root.htm

I tested it with an online scanner and it got 6 hits out of 65, so use at your own risk. However I tried to find information about it and it seems to be ok and the alarams are claimed to be false positives. I used it successfully to root my VF 858, so it works. However if somebody finds out that this is indeed infested with malware then remove this answer or drop a note.

Usage is pretty simple as you just have to connect your device, enable USB debugging and then press the buttons in the Wizard.

Answer (score 0):

The device you mentioned (Vodafone 858 Smart) has a Qualcomm MSM7225 Snapdragon S1 and android 2.2 (from GSMArena).

As far as I know most Qualcomm soc can be rooted. But as you already have a lower android version I won't suggest getting hands dirty. Instead use one click root tools from XDA. Famous ones like dirty cow, one click root, and frama root, etc like old days.

If you still can not root your device use Qualcomm edl method to dump boot img, then use magisk to patch it.